# Connecting Reactjs project to mqtt using MyQttHub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mqtt, iot

I need some help in connecting my react project to myqtt hub to publish and receive data. this is the code I'm using:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var options={
    clientId:"id",
    username:"ArduinoProject",
    password:"ssssss",
    protocolId: "MQTT",
    protocolVersion: 4,
  
     port : 1883 ,
    clean:true};
    var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://node02.myqtthub.com/",options)

client.on('connect', () => {
    alert('Connected!');
   
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.publish('testingfromnode','Dou You see mee?');

console.log(client.clientId);
console.log(JSON.stringify(client.options));


class Garage extends Component {
   
   
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>HEllooo</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Garage;
```

For some reason I'm having an error saying: *WebSocket connection to 'ws://node02.myqtthub.com:1883/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response.*

The HTML I wrote is appearing however I'm not able to connect to the mqtt broker.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already posted the question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274093/connecting-reactjs-to-myqtthub) and this one should be closed as duplicate, but I suppose you're desperate for an answer at this point. Where did you get the port value of `1883` from? I suppose you just copied it from the sample *JD Allen* have provided in the comments. Ofcourse it is not gonna work, it was just a sample value.

So, according to their [Official guide for Node-Red](https://support.asplhosting.com/t/connecting-to-myqtthub-with-node-red-programming-tool/249) you should be using port `8883`. Also, I am pretty sure your `clientId` is not `id`, you should fetch that from your hub.

If you're still getting an error related to the handshake, you're most probably having protocol version mismatch on your server and client. Checkout the [docs for the npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) and more specifically the section about [web sockets](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md).

This should pretty much solve the handshake problem. From then on, you'll have other issues as you're not subscribing to any topics in your code. Once again, check the `mqtt`'s package docs.

This question should help you as well: [MQTT.js not connecting from websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000448/mqtt-js-not-connecting-from-websockets).

Comment: I just put id as clientID for the sake of the question, and the same goes for the password. I already tried port 8883 and I had the same error. I'm using these ports because the mqtt broker told me so. And yess! I'm really desperate for an answer.